# Number of Permutations of the Set $\{x_1, x_2, ... , x_n, y_1, y_2, ... y_n\}$ where $x_i, y_i$ are not next to each other

Tags: inclusion-exclusion

I'd like to find the number of permutations of the set

$$\{x_1, x_2, ... , x_n, y_1, y_2, ... y_n\}$$ where that $x_i, y_i$ are not consecutively located for each $i \in[n]$

---

**solution**

Let $A_i$ be the collection of cases where $x_i$ and $y_i$ are "next to" each other for given $i$.

Then through the principle of inclusion and exclusion :

$$\mid\cup_{j\in[n]} A_j\mid = \sum_{\emptyset\ne J\subseteq[n]}(-1)^{\mid J \mid-1} \mid\cap_{j\in J} A_j\mid$$

Then our desired number of permutation is its complementary which is :

$$(2n)!-\sum_{\emptyset\ne J\subseteq[n]}(-1)^{\mid J \mid-1} \mid\cap_{j\in J} A_j\mid$$

Additionally, since

$$\mid\cap_{j\in J} A_j\mid = (2n-\mid J \mid)!\cdot 2^{\mid J \mid}$$

The number we want is :

$$(2n)!-\sum_{\emptyset\ne J\subseteq[n]}(-1)^{\mid J \mid-1}(2n-\mid J \mid)!\cdot 2^{\mid J \mid}$$

---

Hereby the Question is:

Is there any margins to be more generalized?

Comment: Do you only want to exclude $y_i$ being right after $x_i$, or also $x_i$ being right after $y_i$? In the latter case, this is the [ménage problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9nage_problem).

Comment: The latter one.

Comment: then it's an non-circled menage problem.